# contruir app native android con capacitor en ionic

Tags: android, ionic, capacitor

Buenas tardes foro tengo un problema cuando hago pruebas de manera local con "ionic serve" los envios http POST me funcionan de manera correcta pero al generar la aplicacion en forma nativa "ionic capacitor add android" -> "ionic capacitor copy android" en teoría todo se genera de manera correcta pero cuando corro en el enmulador de android studio no puedo realizar peticiones POST es como si el API que genero no existiera lo que me causa confusión es que de manera local los CORS los arregle pero en el enmulador no se que este pasando.
Alguien tiene alguna idea de como puedo solucionarlo???

Comment: Creo que este es tu problema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator

Comment: lo checo gracias!

Comment: no me funciona ya que cuando despliego la app me sigue marcando error

Comment: Cuál es el error que obtienes?

Comment: Msg: XMLHttpRequest cannot load "API"  The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8100' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Parece que el origen está configurado para localhost:8100 y en el emulador es diferente. Prueba permitiendo cualquier origen.

Comment: según yo con eso se habilita:

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

Comment: Pero no funciona!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es muy importante que agregues información adicional a tu pregunta en lugar de agregar como comentarios, te sugerimos revisar [ask] y editar tu pregunta, saludos!